# Laravel 4.2 Migrations issue

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-migrations

Can someone help me with this error? Got it during Laravel 4.2 Migrations

> {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer::display() must be an instance of Exception, instance of ParseError given, called in C:\Users\adejaremola\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\GoingFurther\bootstrap\compiled.php on line 9462 and defined in C:\Users\adejaremola\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\GoingFurther\bootstrap\compiled.php:9352\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\Users\adejaremola\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\GoingFurther\bootstrap\compiled.php(9462): Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer->display(Object(ParseError))\n#1 C:\Users\adejaremola\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\GoingFurther\bootstrap\compiled.php(9414): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->displayException(Object(ParseError))\n#2 C:\Users\adejaremola\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\GoingFurther\bootstrap\compiled.php(9418): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleException(Object(ParseError))\n#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleUncaughtException(Object(ParseError))\n#4 {main}\n  thrown","file":"C:\Users\adejaremola\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\GoingFurther\bootstrap\compiled.php","line":9352}}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to call the laravel's migration from the browser. It won't work here unfortunately.

You should run it from the *CLI* using command in the project root:

```
$ php artisan migrate
```